# Turn a makefile into a list of build commands

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Currently I'm building the Linux kernel with the command `make LLVM=1 CFLAGS_KERNEL="-mspeculative-load-hardening" Image` but the build is failing because some files can't handle the `-mspeculative-load-hardening` flag. So what I want to do is turn the `make` command into a shell script consisting of the raw compile commands used to build the kernel. Then I can remove the `-mspeculative-load-hardening` flag from the problematic files manually.

I tried doing this by using `make -n` and piping the output to a file, but it looks like this:

```
make --no-print-directory -C /home/rutvik/kernel-asahi-slh \
-f /home/rutvik/kernel-asahi-slh/Makefile Image
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/basic
:
:
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/dtc
set -e;  echo '  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/dtc.o';   trap 'rm -f scripts/dtc/dtc.o; trap - HUP; kill -s HUP $$' HUP;  trap 'rm -f scripts/dtc/dtc.o; trap - INT; kill -s INT $$' INT;  trap 'rm -f scripts/dtc/dtc.o; trap - QUIT; kill -s QUIT $$' QUIT;  trap 'rm -f scripts/dtc/dtc.o; trap - TERM; kill -s TERM $$' TERM;  trap 'rm -f scripts/dtc/dtc.o; trap - PIPE; kill -s PIPE $$' PIPE; clang -Wp,-MMD,scripts/dtc/.dtc.o.d -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -std=gnu11   -I ./scripts/dtc/libfdt -DNO_YAML  -c -o scripts/dtc/dtc.o scripts/dtc/dtc.c; scripts/basic/fixdep scripts/dtc/.dtc.o.d scripts/dtc/dtc.o 'clang -Wp,-MMD,scripts/dtc/.dtc.o.d -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -std=gnu11   -I ./scripts/dtc/libfdt -DNO_YAML  -c -o scripts/dtc/dtc.o scripts/dtc/dtc.c' > scripts/dtc/.dtc.o.cmd; rm -f scripts/dtc/.dtc.o.d
set -e;  echo '  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/flattree.o';   trap 'rm -f scripts/dtc/flattree.o; trap - HUP; kill -s HUP $$' HUP;  trap 'rm -f scripts/dtc/flattree.o; trap - INT; kill -s INT $$' INT;  trap 'rm -f scripts/dtc/flattree.o; trap - QUIT; kill -s QUIT $$' QUIT;  trap 'rm -f scripts/dtc/flattree.o; trap - TERM; kill -s TERM $$' TERM;  trap 'rm -f scripts/dtc/flattree.o; trap - PIPE; kill -s PIPE $$' PIPE; clang -Wp,-MMD,scripts/dtc/.flattree.o.d -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -std=gnu11   -I ./scripts/dtc/libfdt -DNO_YAML  -c -o scripts/dtc/flattree.o scripts/dtc/flattree.c; scripts/basic/fixdep scripts/dtc/.flattree.o.d scripts/dtc/flattree.o 'clang -Wp,-MMD,scripts/dtc/.flattree.o.d -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -std=gnu11   -I ./scripts/dtc/libfdt -DNO_YAML  -c -o scripts/dtc/flattree.o scripts/dtc/flattree.c' > scripts/dtc/.flattree.o.cmd; rm -f scripts/dtc/.flattree.o.d
```

All the `make` commands are shown as part of the file. It looks like it's expanding them recursively, but if I try to run this file directly as a shell script, it'll run `make` which is what I want to avoid; I just want the compile commands that make eventually runs.

Is there a way to extract this info from a Makefile? Ideally I'd like to do it without having to modify the Makefile itself since it's quite complicated, but if that's the only way to accomplish my goal then so be it I suppose.

**UPDATE:** It looks like `make -n` by itself isn't extracting all the work that needs to be performed. A lot of preprocessing of files is done by the makefile that isn't part of the `make -n` output. I first need to do an actual build before the dry run even succeeds...

Comment: You just have to skip the make commands.  Simplistically, just pipe the output to `| grep -v ^make`.  There's no way make can do that for you, because make has no idea that the recipe it runs is running another instance of make.  It's just another shell script as far as make is concerned.

Comment: Alternatively, in your script that runs the output define a shell function `make() { :; }` that does nothing; this will be called instead of the `make` program.

Comment: @MadScientist I tried using `| grep "set -e"` to filter out the actual commands, but it looks like there are some hidden steps that don't appear in the `make -n` output. For instance there's a file `dtc-lexer.l` that gets parsed to form `dtc-lexer.lex.c` which is then compiled. The problem is the `make -n` output has the commands to compile the `.c` file but not to produce it. But when I run `make` it of course produces the file. So `make -n` isn't even capturing all the necessary work...

Comment: `make -n` will only run commands that are needed to ensure that out-of-date files are brought up to date.  So if a previous run already created `dtc-lexer.lex.c` then `make -n` won't show that command.  Also, you have omitted any command which does NOT contain `set -e`; are you sure that every single command you want to keep has that string?  Note, that is NOT added by `make` itself so if any of your recipes don't contain it, they won't be selected.  I recommend looking at the raw output to see if the lexer invocation is there.

Comment: Or said differently, it's not true that make will not print some "secret" commands when you run it with `-n`.  It will print out commands for every recipe that make thinks it will need to run.  It can be mistaken: especially if your makefile plays tricks like has a recipe that updates a file which is not listed as a target of that recipe... the only way make can know about that is by actually running the recipe, which of course it will not do when you run `-n`.

Comment: @MadScientist If I try to run `make -n` without first having run `make` I get an error (it doesn't say exactly what went wrong; it just says `error 2`). It might be because the makefile is doing work that isn't a target, as you said. I'll run the actual build with `make V=1` to see if the lexer output shows up.

Comment: @MadScientist After running with `V=1` it looks like the they call `flex` to lex the file. I tried running this output directly while using the `make() { :; }` trick, but I get a weird error saying `KERNELVERSION is not set`. I don't know what exactly is causing this error in the file though, but it seems like progress?

Comment: Who knows what it is doing.  There are all kinds of things: for example, the makefile might contain invocations of the `$(shell ...)` make function to do something, it might set makefile variables then export them so that programs expect to get those values through the environment, or who knows what else that is not captured by `make -n`.  It was never the goal of `make -n` to provide you with an identical script of build commands without `make`.  It can do that, for straightforward makefiles.  But the more "magic" your makefiles use the less likely it is.